# Show Forward/Back (e.g. Next 30) arrows at top of list?

Tags: 2013, list-view, paging

How do I configure a SharePoint List View/Web Part to display the Forward and Back list paging/navigation arrows at the top of the view (as well as at the bottom)?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried search Google first? [sharepoint paging buttons](https://www.google.nl/search?q=sharepoint+paging+buttons&oq=sharepoint+paging+buttons&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64l3.4695j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=0&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 1):

I tried just now a little thing. Here what I got:

1. Open your page where you want to get the paging above the the webpart and use the developertools (1) to find the paging div (2).

[image]

2. Now, add a script editor to you page (e.G. above the library) and via Codeausschnitt bearbeiten (edit snippet) add `<div id="scriptPagingWPQ2></div>` Of course your id might be different.

[image]

3. Now save everything and your paging is above the library. Hope this helps a little or at least gives you a starting point.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I'd prefer that it would appear below the View Names/Search Box.